# How to "undelete" in Stack Exchange in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request, verbs, modern-life, technology

In the Stack Exchange network questions, answers, and comments can be undeleted.
What would be a good Latin verb for "undelete" in this context?
To "delete" is naturally *delere*, but I see no good way to prefix it into anything understandable.
The best option I could think of is *restituere*.
Is this the best choice?
Are there other good verbs for bringing something back to existence?

Answer (score 3):

I'd think of *[reverti](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0060:entry=revertor)* "to bring back".

BTW, *undelete* is very idiomatic English and cannot be translated in a 1-to-1-fashion to many other languages. In German user interfaces the word *rückgängig* ist used (from *rückgängig machen*, for English back-translations see [e.g., this dictionary](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/r%C3%BCckg%C3%A4ngig%20machen).

Comment: If the verb is used for undeleting instead of being undeleted (the subject being a user, not a post), shouldn't it be *revertere* instead of *reverti*?

Comment: I thought it was mainly used as a deponens and not in the formally active forms.

Comment: Hmm... It's possible, but it sounds a little weird at first. Comparing *revertere* and *reverti* calls for a follow-up question. Whichever form is preferred for this use, I agree that this is a good verb.

Comment: The answer to my [follow-up question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/6007/79) indicates that *reverti* is intransitive, so it can't be used to for undeleting a post on a SE site. It is a good verb for the post being undeleted, though.