# Revertere or reverti in transitive use?

Tags: vocabulary, verbs, deponent-verbs, object

If I want to use the verb *revertere/reverti* transitively (with an object different from the subject), should I choose active or passive forms?
Intuition suggests that active forms are preferred for transitive use, but if the verb is deponent, this does not necessarily apply.
The examples in [L&S for *reverti*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0060:entry=revertor) seem all intransitive and [the entry for *revertere*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aalphabetic+letter%3Dr%3Aentry+group%3D12%3Aentry%3Dreverto) doesn't help much.
Or is the answer that this verb is intransitive and I cannot say *hanc rem reverto* at all?

It seems that the key questions are:

1. Can the verb be used transitively?
2. Is it deponent?

This question arose from an answer to [a question regarding the verb "undelete"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5997/79).
I would like to describe turning something back into an earlier state.
If you have ideas for expressing that, please answer the linked question.

Comment: Castiglioni-Mariotti: "In gener. le forme attive si trovano  al perf. e tempi derivati; le dep. al pres., imperf., fut."

Comment: @AlexB. Quella sarebbe una buona risposta. Vuoi scriverla?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OLD says the following:

> "usu. dep. in pres. system, active in pf. system. Dep. pf. mostly post-Augustan."

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I addition, the entry seems to say "intr[ansitive]". That with the description of deponency makes a very complete answer.